# Is there a way to copy the 'authorization' parameter from the browser?

Tags: javascript

In firefox when the user opens inspect tools -> network -> Headers, can I get/import with javascript somehow the displayed API 'Authorization' parameter which stores the access API token? Or maybe is there a way to store a log from the traffic and the open the file with javascript and scan for the token ? I would need this log to automatically be downloaded once every day so I can scan through it. Has anyone done something similar ?

Comment: I have not done that but if you are using any ajax then you can log or store such header.

Comment: Can you share how to obtain this ?

Comment: I don't use firefox so I don't really know but I do this all the time in Chrome. Just open the "network" tab in the developer tool. Firefox may have the same thing because it was the first browser to implement the network tab

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), you can access the headers of a response via its `headers` read-only property.  This property contains the [Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers) object which includes all the non-forbidden header in the response, including `Authorization` if one has been set.  Below is some example code for how you would print it in the console:

```
fetch('https://www.example.com/api/v1/widgets')
.then((response) => {
  console.log(response.headers['Authorization'])
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just use the developer tool. Open the developer tool then switch to the "Network" tab. From there you can see all http requests (refresh the page if it is empty). Then just select the request you want and copy the data you want from the header.

You can copy it just like in any other program - click on it, select what you want to copy then press `ctrl-c` (or `cmd-c` on Mac)

[image]